# How do I use SharedPreferences and Context in the model layer in Android?

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I am using clean architecture and the model layer has a repository, a retrofit interface and a class that implements the repository and creates the retrofit service. I am using this example: https://github.com/saulmm/Avengers

Here are the classes:
Retrofit api service

```
 public interface ApiService {


    @GET("api/events")
        Observable<List<Event>> getEvents();

    @GET("api/event/{id}")
        Observable<Event> getEvent(@Path("id") int id);


    @Multipart()
    @POST("api/events")
        Observable<Event> postEvent(@Part("venue") Venue venue,
                                    @Part RequestBody image,
                                    @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params
                                   );
    }
```

Repository

```
public interface WyatRepository {




    Observable<List<Event>> getEvents();


    Observable<Event> getEvent(int id);


    Observable<Event> postEvent(Venue venue, String path, Map map);
}
```

and the rest data source class:

```
public class RestDataSource implements WyatRepository {

    public final static  String ENDPOINT = "http://xxxxxxxx.com/";
    private final ApiService apiService;


    public RestDataSource() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        client.interceptors().add(loggingInterceptor);

        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original =chain.request();

                Request request = original.newBuilder().header("Authorization",new SharedPreferencesUtil(getBaseContext()).getToken)
                        .method(original.method(),original.body())
                        .build();



                return null;
            }
        });


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Album> getAlbum(int id) {
        return apiService.getAlbum(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<List<Event>> getEvents() {
        return apiService.getEvents();
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Event> getEvent(int id) {
        return apiService.getEvent(id);
    }
```

My question is in the last class where in the constructor I am using the SharedPrefences but I get an error because I can't use android context or SharedPreferences to get the access token that is saved because it is the model layer. How do I resolve this issue so that I can use an access token from the model layer without using any com.android classes?

Comment: Do you expect the Token to change at runtime? Otherwise why not just injecting it in the RestDataSource constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is set your `Authorization` dynamically like this:

```
 @GET("api/event/{id}")
 Observable<Event> getEvent(@Header("Authorization") String  authHeader,      
                            @Path("id") int id);
```

or in your method you can pass context:

```
public RestDataSource(Context context) {
   // now you can access your shared preferences
}
```

Comment: If I use the first way do I need to set the token in my constructor?

Comment: you need to pass it just like you are passing @path data

Answer (score 0):

You can pass context of activity or fragment in constructor of RestDataSource

```
    public RestDataSource(Context context) {

                    Request request = original.newBuilder().header("Authorization",new SharedPreferencesUtil(context).getToken)
                            .method(original.method(),original.body())
                            .build();

}
```

If you are calling this class from activity you can use

```
RestDataSource rest=new RestDataSource(this);
```

or if you are using from fragment

```
RestDataSource rest=new RestDataSource(getActivity());
```